# How to implement measure functionality on map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to implement Measure functionality on openstreet map. Measure is adding two points on a map and find the distance between those points.

For that I referred https://github.com/danstowell/openstreetmap-website/commits/jsrouting-contextmenu

It will work fine except water area/region on openstreet map. In my case I am rendering my own maps on my project, so this is not work for me.

I am using below Environment:

Environment : Rails 4 and Ruby 2

Anyone know about it?

How do I implement measure functionality on my map?

Is there any other ways to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the specifics relating to OSM, however assuming that you can convert the points to geodetic points then you can use the haversine or vincenty formulas to get the great circle distance:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

OSM uses a spherical Mercator projection.  If all you have are 2d Cartesian (projected) coordinates then you will need to convert these to geodetic coordinates.

If you also need to take into account terrain then this gets more complex but maybe OSM provides something for this that gives heights along a transect line.